# Isomorphism with fixed number of Permutations

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, isomorphism-testing

Suppose, I have a fixed number of permutations for each sub-graph to determine isomorphism of whole graph. Is it possible to   determine  efficiently ?

For example, $G, H$ are isomorphic graphs.  For  subgraphs  $G_1, G_2, G_3$      of graph $G$ there are sets of permutation $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$ (each of them has $k$  permutations).  We can  check by constructing direct product, but it is not efficient.

---

Suppose, $G^{P} =H$ where  $P$ is an isomorphism. Let, $P$ is a direct product of   permutations $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3$ where $\pi_1$ permutes vertices of $G_1$, $\pi_2$ permutes vertices of $G_2$, $\pi_3$ permutes vertices of $G_3$. In other words, $\pi_i$ acts on $G_i$ such that $G$ transforms to  graph $H$.

Now, assume there is an ***oracle*** that gives you a set of  $n$ permutations for each $G_i$. Say, the set is $\beta_i$.  In these $n$ permutations, one is $\pi_i$.  So, you know , there is permutation that transform subgraph $G_i$ to $H_i$, but you don't know which one.
If you just find all possible direct product, you will know, but that is exponential, thus inefficient.

A relevant question is asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/240350/generating-set-of-graph-automorphism-from-direct-product).

Comment: Could you elaborate/clarify? I am having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: @verret , I have added an example, please, have look.

Comment: If there are $n$ permutations for each of three subgraphs, then checking all possibilities is $O(n^3)$, not exponential. Or are you interested in this question for arbitrarily large values of $3$?

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher, $3$ is for an illustration, graph has $x=n/c$ subgraphs, in general, where $n$ is the number of vertices of $graph$ and $c$ is a constant.